# Can anyone identify this warship?

Tags: world-war-two, naval

The picture is of [a ship that my late father](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRFlX.jpg) is believed to have served on, I can find no identification marks on the photograph, so even a type of vessel would be a great help, as I have no records of his service history.

[image]

Comment: The miracle of image search.

Answer (score 41):

**That photo is of the *HMS Liberty*, retouched to remove identifying information.**

This [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivAWO9_1Z618KXIN4H-kBs4tMDqqf0zYjl5fggZhbVCcjt9SRvT_1MwAayFxrr8SDZX1i7hUkozYKw06UAQup8z2P0UCVfAwU4en02BfSw38B9f0_1cZBKOOHilLWequNYS4_1mcXbSwRZ1mipe50J5L0vmhEiZEuZJabMOKd0PV76ChWlVs976WUNI-5XXFCAa4THRcni_1vEX4ZnK_1irQWf49NWFCAkzdkpao2PLg6LAl0Pz2sJ40sNy_1bWfCdCxd6PDnyNyOQRSOwnrL97CjfvzOUrVVrRCd0BtHkpE4VGOmB-IXnFyIKDev9MsfhlkPm9qkdoBmlBdX6hJDDGRK7qFd_1MVcerQ0iN9Vg3avdWKc3uGJJZAeVV62umePoS98hMEojr8Ly5FGiPbxS9noxOmp0xfFlHNJUIBOSjsKe96l-bWZv9jf_1pt1LCdU4V2aYI0LV4WFyUpe_1obLlQEfrCBdo_1_1AWjy6s0HTko_1Wio13FXnsrZepFOSyxyjP7wYSGwxXPZy7VMg02nH-TYHsKgvIp1L3hWOOdoMreQcHLmmK-xCCnKyLP_1fwDrBqHN7kfU0N8OGFQOhl3FXiWI7rg9zjagox64aqivK0oNlIkLZlnolnAzuvqXWhYZOSOYF-DIJa0PESPor1_1ZNp7B5Q4V6EP4AcXarDeT8iIUKBjGZu6cOs2CVM0SjtZNKisiF26PDkXQH6EoxknRaJWmGbFy3vxqIVHtWtudE--mOGlXemWREiV_1ecgD6ccr-1Ohu_1P91bqaYLS19luGNSSrLdOlmPVxlUHqd6C8SKuA_1i9CpXle4PWK4lp82yMLN2z_1CaI2YmbXW-VaPLR_1JlyphpYYmxydBBjX5rWdaljWPW4KzcDvmqrp27gbMLTdZM62_1q6947CS-pnVZg9CMEwv5cMuWkF8svgbXMuD2BE0fVHbr3FlCpHNIV0rjmCWxAzgM-puizJmDJ3qdJuPz7CkxPZFklaYeXTBKOQeqUWRjNVJqzv7_1UKSouMxIEcRD9ybejPqQpdmM6UVIS_1atpNupzFJ1iCHc6ekzwL-OqnTup9T73yYEEM9tBRuhS_1MoGbYawR3O189SEjU7yNYnp5V_1QPD_1GSEuSGfZgHWnhrICvxWJe8cgt7HbgZzh2d0_1i3bke-bMwlNtDcn_10igIbW5CgEbcv2mpbADnw5FiAo9gJrOv3eHRhA8PDK6zh-o999m8PjHQNYRCJAyPHkQ-dYf3AbKZg7bt4BN1rOXcWBg_1AE1V-sCQQczkcvKU5Iz3tlbcblEfElD3mkJf4XcOlCIGmuWH8N6E2MrPSL29UegY76gWy1qKS6JqHDZ0zXEXL5raS3WCEmGVnKKbLh-mfXVT-tGPC2cDzPhDWwyYVA-PiPq6k-_1Rs2I7mWoaccTMMIpShYjAaiYnIfBct_1qj698uxBxlSckBFGvBqHQ4j1KcVeha_1EAl8QjnWoi3jxgn4PTJ9CNa2KCsRVevpj6e05Em7k9IjsoSd1MfrxCEl6f8mbwvLtGJGqw25KbywMc3Aucfjzh0JGfb5z)<sup>1</sup> finds images identified as both [***HMS Lysander***](http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205121201) **and** [***HMS Liberty***](http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205121164).<sup>2</sup>  Looking at those two pages, they're the same photo, but with retouching to remove the flags, land, and ship's numbers:
[image: animated difference]

Looking closely at your photo, the area where the ship's numbers would be shows signs of editing:
[image: Numbers retouched]

The flags were airbrushed out too:
[image: flags retouched]

I wrote to the [Imperial War Museum](http://www.iwm.org.uk/) and got a response back from a curator there:

> Thank you for contacting the IWM with this information. These two records are both clearly the same image of HMS Liberty, and represent an interesting example of wartime photographic censorship.
>
> I have amended the catalogue records of both entries to reflect the relationship between the two, and these changes will migrate into our Collections Search database in due course.

The photo is definitively of the *HMS Liberty*, but was previously identified as being of the *HMS Lysander* for reasons unclear.  Hopefully narrowing the possibilities to those two ships helps with determining which ship your father served on.

---

<sup>1</sup> Based on [Retroswald's answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/20712/4026).
<sup>2</sup> When originally written, the retouched photo was identified as the *HMS Lysander* on the Imperial War Museum's page (and others).  It's unclear how it came to be identified as such, but the records have since been corrected because of this answer.  Observation is participation.

Comment: Great sleuthing!  Have you contacted the IWM about this?

Comment: @Schwern I just sent them an email.  We'll see what comes of it.

Comment: [According to this source](http://www.worldnavalships.com/directory/shipinfo.php?ShipID=1991), J391 is HMS Liberty, so both photos are of HMS Liberty.  The OP's father could have served on almost any Algerine Class.

Comment: @Schwern I'm curious as to how the IWM came to identify OP's photo as being of the HMS Lysander.

Comment: @blahdiblah It says it is the Lysander if you do a google image search. Unless you dig deeper to find out what this person did, then it is, at first glance, the Lysander.

Comment: @Joehot200 The original, unretouched photo has J391 on the ship which is [HMS Liberty](http://www.worldnavalships.com/directory/shipinfo.php?ShipID=1991).  HMS Lysander was [J/M379](http://www.worldnavalships.com/directory/shipinfo.php?ShipID=1995).  Everyone on Google are likely repeating the IWM's mistake which is repeating what the Royal Navy / Ministry Of Defence Foxhill said about their retouched photos.

Comment: This picture is pretty clearly a copy of the picture the OP gave. The clouds are identical.

Comment: J391 was HMS Liberty. My father served on her in 1945 in the North Sea. It was his first ship, not something one forgets.

Answer (score 14):

With the help of Search Google for this image, that ship is HMS Lysander.

For more info click the following links.

1. [World Naval Ships Website](http://www.worldnavalships.com/directory/shipinfo.php?ShipID=1995)
2. [UBoat.Net Website](http://www.uboat.net/allies/warships/ship/3817.html)

Comment: Readily done in Chrome. Maybe not so easy in other browsers. +1 for including the answer and method.

Comment: It would be *really* nifty if you could include the resulting search page too, linked to your "Search Google" text. Easy to do here with the editor.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid response and the, for me very valuable information.

Comment: Just so you know, that is one of a class of ~110 Algerine Class Minesweepers.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 of my father's pictures from his service in the Royal Navy in WW2-they are identical to this and it is HMS Lysander-fleet minesweeper.

Comment: Could you add those photos as source? Would improve the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Pennant number J391 was allocated to HMS Liberty, she was sold to Belgium post war and became Adrien De Gerlache

Comment: That part number wasn't in the question though, so this is really more of a comment on another answer, isn't it? Also how did you come by this information?